# Server logs to Dojo Front end, appropriate data storage method?

Tags: ajax, logging, dojo

Good Morning all, I am currently building a tool which scrapes a number of figures from various logs on several different servers using AUX and Shell scripts on a minute by minute basis. Currently I have scripts that produce HTML files also on a minute by minute basis so that I can look back and see the system health for any given minute. So essentially these HTML files as being used as the archiving medium, which obviously is very strange.

Taking this tool forward I am looking to build a front end on a DOJO platform which will support widgets and graphs for each of the different data sets that is gathered from the logs. I haven't used DOJO much in the past and was hoping that somebody more experienced in the technology would be able to tell me what storage medium I should be using for these simple metrics that are produced by the scripts every minute. I have heard of the JSON method but am not sure.

Thanks for your time!

Jonny

Comment: JSON is definately the way to go - or XML perhaps if you find this more suitable reading from a server commandline pov. Best option imho would be a database though, a simple table with one field pr value plus an id and a timestamp. Look into `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` or `dojox.data.JsonRestStore`

Comment: Show a snippet of your data, tell which server language / http daemon your targeting etc so ppl can get the better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this in the rare chance it may be stumbled upon by another user. I decided that JSON was definitely the way forward. Each minute I have a system that produces a JSON files like the below.

```
{
"DataDTS"   : "2014.05.02-09:00",
"System"    : "Performance Test",
"SourceServer"  : "gb02qws122debx7",
"OldestData"    : "2014.05.02-09:00",

"MetricData" : {

    "FredHopper Direct" : {
        "Small" : "FH",
        "Type" : "ByMinute",
        "HeaderLevels" : 1,
        "Data": { "Failures":0, "Avg":"0.318", "Min":"0.306", "Max":"0.340" }
    },

    "Performance By Instance" : {
        "Small" : "RATE",
        "Type" : "ByMinute",
        "HeaderLevels" : 2,
        "Sections" : {
            "102.01" : { "Attributes" : ["(20)"], "Data": { "Req":"999", "Avg Resp":"0.254" } },
            "102.02" : { "Attributes" : ["(20)"], "Data": { "Req":"144", "Avg Resp":"0.376" } },
            "103.01" : { "Attributes" : ["(20)"], "Data": { "Req":"168", "Avg Resp":"0.199" } },
            "103.02" : { "Attributes" : ["(20)"], "Data": { "Req":"152", "Avg Resp":"0.283" } },
            "Unallocated" : { "Attributes": [], "Data": {"Req":"87", "Avg Resp":"0.154"} },
            "qws122" : { "Attributes": [], "Data": {"Tot Req":"460", "Rate PPS":"7.7"} }
        }
    },


    "HTML Status" : {
        "Small" : "HTML",
        "Type" : "Status",
        "HeaderLevels" : 1,
        "Data" : [
            { "Code":"200", "Req":447 },
            { "Code":"206", "Req":1 },
            { "Code":"301", "Req":7 },
            { "Code":"302", "Req":5 },
            { "Code":"TOT", "Req":460 }
        ]
    },

    "Page Breakdown" : {
        "Small" : "PB",
        "Type" : "Status",
        "HeaderLevels" : 2,
        "Sections" : {
            "Top 15 Average Response Times" : { 
                "Attributes": [],
                "Data" : [
                    { "URL":"men", "Req":1, "Avg Resp":"3.597", "Cached":"0.0%" },
                    { "URL":"jacques-vert", "Req":1, "Avg Resp":"3.335", "Cached":"0.0%" },
                    { "URL":"OrderOKView", "Req":1, "Avg Resp":"1.615", "Cached":"0.0%" },
                    { "URL":"warehouse", "Req":1, "Avg Resp":"1.050", "Cached":"0.0%" }
                ]
            },                  
            "Top 15 Requests" : {
                "Attributes": [],
                "Data" : [
                    { "URL":"Navigate", "Req":220, "Avg Resp":"0.372", "Cached":"26.4%" },
                    { "URL":"prod", "Req":42, "Avg Resp":"0.186", "Cached":"13.5%" },
                    { "URL":"sureroute-test-object.html", "Req":24, "Avg Resp":"0.001", "Cached":"0.0%" },
                    { "URL":"TopCategories1", "Req":8, "Avg Resp":"0.032", "Cached":"0.0%" }
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    "App server CPU" : {
        "Small" : "CPU",
        "Type" : "ByMinute",
        "HeaderLevels" : 2,
        "Sections" : {
            "qap302" : { "Attributes" : ["Ent:7.0", "Max:8.0", "Mem:32768MB", "Wgt:200"], "Data": { "usr%":"16.8", "iow%":"1.4", "phy":"1.8", "ent%":"25.1" } },
            "qap312" : { "Attributes" : ["Ent:7.0", "Max:8.0", "Mem:32768MB", "Wgt:200"], "Data": { "usr%":"8.1", "iow%":"0.1", "phy":"0.8", "ent%":"11.0" } }
        }
    }

}
```